# How can I search an XML file without a dynamic language?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, search

Let me try to explain my situation:

We are using a CMS which 'bakes' a website, and you publish it to a webserver.  The published site contains only static HTML ( or XML ) pages ( generated from the content in the CMS database ).

I imported an XML file with the names and phone numbers from the company phone directory.

Using only XSLT, can I create a way to search that directory?

For example, if my XML file, directory.xml looks like this:

```
<directory>
<person>
 <fname>Ryan</fname>
 <lname>Purple</lname>
  <phone>887 778 5544</phone>
</person>
<person>
  <fname>Tanya</fname>
  <lname>Orange</lname>
  <phone>887 998 5541</phone>
</person>
<directory>
```

Can I create a way to search for a person with the last name starting with "Pur" ?

1. Can I pass a parameter to the XSLT?
2. Can I search the XML tree to match the string in the parameter?

Comment: Technically, you could, the question is how you're going to implement XSLT provided that your web system is static html, and I assume your XML file isn't going to be downloaded by every client, or is it? If it is, you could use XSLT on the client side, but that is hardly an effective way to do it.

Comment: I have to deal with a similar CMS at my work.. You have my condolences.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer to all your questions and for a complete, short and efficient XSLT solution. :)

Comment: This sounds more like a webmaster question. If nothing can be executed in server (static content), then everything must be executed in client side. If you are going to search a database, that database should be download to client side also. If it's a big database, people are going to hate you, I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using only XSLT, can I create a way to
>   search that directory?

**Yes.**

> Can I create a way to search for a
>   person with the last name starting
>   with "Pur" ?

**Yes.** In fact, the transformation below allows to search for text starting with any 2,3,4 or 5 characters. It can be generalized to allow search for a starting string up to any predefined maximum length.

> 1.Can I pass a parameter to the XSLT?

**Yes**. The details how to do this depend on the particular XSLT processor that is used. For example **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addparam.aspx)** is how to pass external parameters to the .NET [**`XslCompiledTransform.Transform()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163434.aspx)

> 2.Can I search the XML tree to match the string in the parameter?

**Yes. This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pPattern" select="'Pur'"/>

 <xsl:key name="kPersonByLNameStart"
  match="person"  use="substring(lname,1,2)"/>
 <xsl:key name="kPersonByLNameStart"
  match="person"  use="substring(lname,1,3)"/>
 <xsl:key name="kPersonByLNameStart"
  match="person"  use="substring(lname,1,4)"/>
 <xsl:key name="kPersonByLNameStart"
  match="person"  use="substring(lname,1,5)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <results>
   <xsl:copy-of select=
    "key('kPersonByLNameStart', $pPattern)"/>
  </results>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (the provided XML document -- corrected to be well-formed and extended):

```
<directory>
    <person>
        <fname>Ryan</fname>
        <lname>Purple</lname>
        <phone>887 778 5544</phone>
    </person>
    <person>
        <fname>Tanya</fname>
        <lname>Orange</lname>
        <phone>887 998 5541</phone>
    </person>
    <person>
        <fname>Martin</fname>
        <lname>Purr</lname>
        <phone>887 778 5544</phone>
    </person>
</directory>
```

**produces the wanted, correct results and in the most efficient way**:

```
<results>
   <person>
      <fname>Ryan</fname>
      <lname>Purple</lname>
      <phone>887 778 5544</phone>
   </person>
   <person>
      <fname>Martin</fname>
      <lname>Purr</lname>
      <phone>887 778 5544</phone>
   </person>
</results>
```

**Do Note**:

This code shows how to search efficiently for text having some prefix of length 2 or 3 or 4 or 5.

Answer (score 0):

How about AJAX? That should run without server-side assistance and will read your xml perfectly. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlfile.asp) has a good intro.

Edited: Blah, sorry, that's useless..I'd forgotten that even here, you need to use a server-side script :/